# How to substitute inf by 100?

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataset I have a column that contains `inf`. I try to substitute it by 100, but get an error `TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'`. All the other values in this column are numeric.

How can I substitute `inf` by 100?

```
fresult.col1.replace(to_replace=dict(inf='100'), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `np.inf`:

```
fresult = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, np.inf]})
print (fresult)
       col1
0  1.000000
1       inf

fresult.col1 = fresult.col1.replace(np.inf, 100)
print (fresult)
    col1
0    1.0
1  100.0
```

If some values which cannot be converted [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) add parameter `errors='coerce'` - it replace it by `NaN`.

```
fresult = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, np.inf, 'a', 'inf']})
print (fresult)
  col1
0    1
1  inf <- numpy.inf
2    a
3  inf <-text inf

fresult.col1 = pd.to_numeric(fresult.col1, errors='coerce').replace(np.inf, 100)
print (fresult)
    col1
0    1.0
1  100.0
2    NaN
3  100.0
```

If only text `inf`:

```
fresult = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, np.inf, 'inf']})
print (fresult)
  col1
0    1
1  inf
2  inf

print (type(fresult.col1.iat[1]))
<class 'float'>

print (type(fresult.col1.iat[2]))
<class 'str'>

fresult.col1 = pd.to_numeric(fresult.col1).replace(np.inf, 100)
print (fresult)
    col1
0    1.0
1  100.0
2  100.0
```

Comment: Why do you hae the first row as `NaN`?

Comment: Only for check if dont replace `NaN` too ;)

Comment: But it is not necessary, I removed it.

Comment: Ok, but how can I check all unique values of this column just to be sure that all numeric values are numeric?

Comment: Hmmm, it is weird. It seems some data are not numeric. Try check it by `pd.to_numeric(fresult.col1, errors='coerce')` - it replace all not numeric values to `NaN`

Comment: Or maybe there is text represenation of `inf`, function `to_numeric` convert it to `np.inf`